# Python error cascade leading to "ValueError: Shape Mismach"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

for the past day or so i have been trying to fix a restriction of a program which i downloaded off of github, the program graphs mee6 leaderboard data using matplotlib (a library i am unfamiliar with).

The problem was that the program can only graph up to the top 1000 people, while i wanted to graph more than 3000.

What i did was replace all instances of 1000 with 3000, and 999 with 2999, as i don't have the knoledge needed to find a deeper fix.

Then i got the following error (it's a long one).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\Downloads\mee6-leaderboard-graphs-master\grapher.py", line 50, in <module>
    server.rankbar(yvar)
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\Downloads\mee6-leaderboard-graphs-master\ServerInfo.py", line 129, in rankbar
    plt.bar(labels, bars)
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2387, in bar
    return gca().bar(
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2342, in bar
    x, height, width, y, linewidth, hatch = np.broadcast_arrays(
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in broadcast_arrays
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 539, in broadcast_arrays
    shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kfir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 421, in _broadcast_shape
    b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (3000,) and arg 1 with shape (1000,).
```

As you can see, the error bounces from the main file to a secondary file, to matplotlib and eventually to numpy.

My best guesses at the sources of the error:

```
def __init__(self, URL, top=100): 
        res = requests.get(URL)
        # res.json() is now the entire webpage API as a dictionary
        print("Communicating with the Mee6 servers...")
        self.servername = res.json()["guild"]["name"]
        print("server name: " + str(self.servername))
        # catches errors associated with inputs for top n members
        maxtop = False
        if top < 3: 
            top = 3
            print("top: cannot be less than 3, changed to 3")
        elif top > 3000: 
            top = 3000
            print("top: cannot be greater than 3000, changed to 3000")
        # special case to handle if top == 1000
        if top == 3000: 
            maxtop = True
            top = 2999
        # the members information is contained in a list of 100(default) dictionaries, one dictionary per member
        username, discordtag, exp, level, messages = [], [], [], [], []
        print("number of members in server:", len(res.json()["players"]))
        # makes sure the server has enough members to graph the top 100/1000 of, else, cap it at an amount
        if top > len(res.json()["players"]):
            top = len(res.json()["players"])
            print("top: cannot be greater than number of members in server, changed to", len(res.json()["players"]))
        if maxtop: 
            self.username, self.discordtag, self.exp, self.level, self.messages = username + [username[-1]], discordtag + [discordtag[-1]], exp + [exp[-1]], level + [level[-1]], messages + [messages[-1]]
            top = 3000
        else: 
            self.username, self.discordtag, self.exp, self.level, self.messages = username, discordtag, exp, level, messages
        self.top = top
```

```
def rankbar(self, yvar="lvl"): 
        """
        yvar: str, determines the dependent variable. 'lvl' for levels, 'exp' for experience points
        """
        # leaderboard visualized
        if yvar == "exp": 
            bars = self.exp[0:self.top]
            yvarname = "Experience"
            print("yvar: exp")
        else: 
            bars = self.level[0:self.top]
            yvarname = "Level"
            print("yvar: lvl")
        labels = list(range(1, self.top + 1))
        plt.bar(labels, bars)
        plt.title("Leaderboard")
        plt.xlabel('Rank')
        plt.ylabel(yvarname)
        plt.grid()
```

also there is this comment:

> Somehow the json link only contains the top 999 entries

which i hope has a work-around.

Comment: You have to identify what array is still size (1000,).

Comment: You should put the line ` if top > len(res.json()["players"]):  top = len(res.json()["players"])` after the lines where you set `top = 3000`. Also, if the API only gives you 999 entries, it is very hard to plot more.  You'll need to find out how to call the API to get more entries, provided the API allows such. This depends on the API author.